# Removing the border in primeng p-tree component for expansion

Tags: angular, primeng

Which is the best way to remove the border in a primeng component during the expansion.

In my view, the below screenshot will just confuse user as there is an treenode with border and a selected treenode with background color.

So I want to get rid of the treenode border while expansion.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out to

```
.ui-treenode-content:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with primeng version 17+ i figure out to

```
.p-treenode-content {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.p-tree-filter {
  outline: 0 none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: inherit;
}
```